# Defining a variable in the condition part of an if-statement?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, standards

I was just shocked, that this is allowed:

```
if( int* x = new int( 20 ) )
{
    std::cout << *x << "!\n";
    // delete x;
}
else
{
    std::cout << *x << "!!!\n";
    // delete x;
}
// std:cout << *x; // error - x is not defined in this scope
```

So, is this allowed by the standard or it's just a compiler extension?

---

<sub>P.S. As there were several comments about this - please *ignore* that this example is "bad" or dangerous. I know what. This is just the first thing, that came to my mind, as an example.</sub>

Comment: Good question, and seems that you have a C background in your mind - +1 for that. :)

Comment: @H2CO3 - thanks :) But what about the `C`? You mean, that this is not allowed there and this may have made me think, that it's not allowed in C++?

Comment: @H2CO3 - Haha, thanks :) I didn't have anything in mind, I was even wondering if this the same in C :))

Comment: since it's only standard in C99...

Comment: Needed `new (std::nothrow)` version - otherwise your example will never go to `else` because of throwing `std::bad_alloc` on allocation error.

Comment: @PiotrNycz - I know. That's just an example, that first came to mi mind.

Comment: Some compilers will let you promote this to a warning (and thus an error) but in the GCC 4.7.3 man pages I can't seem to find a way to do that now - neither -Wall, -Wextra or -pedantic seemed to do it.

Comment: Why are the `delete x;` lines commented out? Is it because they aren't needed for pointers dynamically allocated in an `if` statement? Or was that just to show that even if you don't delete `x` the pointer is not available outside the `if`? And does that mean the example above has a memory leak?

Comment: @Dan - that's really silly example. Yes, there's a memory leak in the code above. I was trying to `cout` the `x` outside the `if` to see if its value is correct, that's why I didn't `delete` it, but it was even a compile time error.

Comment: @KirilKirov No problem. I too was surprised this worked to begin with and stumbled on your question well trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This is allowed by the specification, since C++98.

From Section 6.4 "Selection statements":

> A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the type-specifier-seq or the declarator of the condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements controlled by the condition.

The following example is from the same section:

```
if (int x = f()) {
    int x;    // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
}
else {
    int x;    // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
}
```

Comment: Goodness! I just realized (thanks to this quote) that the name was in scope in `else` as well. Somehow I always thought it would just be available in the `if` section...

Answer (score 21):

Not really an answer (but comments are not well suited to code samples), more a reason why it's incredibly handy:

```
if (int* x = f()) {
    std::cout << *x << "\n";
}
```

Whenever an API returns an "option" type (which also happens to have a boolean conversion available), this type of construct can be leveraged so that the variable is only accessible within a context where it is sensible to use its value. It's a really powerful idiom.

Comment: I had never seen this from the point of view of option types and would always heavily miss them when coding in C++. Thanks for changing my life for the better!

Comment: @Matthieu M. I don't quite get your point on an option type. Could you expand on the mentioned idiom or give some additional link. Sounds quite interesting. For the moment I use boost::optional for such things. Do you mean to use a plain pointer like an optional type and have a limited scope for it or is there more behind it

Comment: @Martin: by option type I mean types that like pointers (or `boost::optional`) have a "sentinel" value to signal the absence of real value. If they also provide a conversion to bool whose value depends solely on the presence/absence of real value held in the type, then the idiom works. For example: `if (boost::optional<int> x = f()) { std::cout << *x << '\n'; }` also works.

Answer (score 19):

It is standard, even in the old C++ 98 version of the language:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Definition of a variable in the conditional part of a `while`, `if`, and `switch` statement are standard. The relevant clause is 6.4 [stmt.select] paragraph 1 which defines the syntax for the condition.

BTW, your use is pointless: if `new` fails it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: It was just an example. I know, it's bad. It was just the first thing, that came to my mind.

Comment: Is optimum to define a variable in the ''''while'''' part?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example demonstrating non typical use of a variable declared in an *if* condition.

Type of variable is `int &` which is both convertible to boolean and useable in the *then* and *else* branches.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> names {"john", "john", "jack", "john", "jack"};
names.push_back("bill"); // without this push_back, my g++ generated exe fails :-(
map<string, int> ages;
int babies = 0;
for (const auto & name : names) {
    if (int & age = ages[name]) {
        cout << name << " is already " << age++ << " year-old" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << name << " was just born as baby #" << ++babies << endl;
        ++age;
    }
}
```

output is

```
john was just born as baby #1
john is already 1 year-old
jack was just born as baby #2
john is already 2 year-old
jack is already 1 year-old
bill was just born as baby #3
```

Unfortunately, the variable in the condition may only be declared with the '=' declaration syntax.

This rules out other possibly useful cases of types with an explicit constructor.

For instance, next example using an `std::ifstream` won't compile ...

```
if (std::ifstream is ("c:/tmp/input1.txt")) { // won't compile!
    std::cout << "true: " << is.rdbuf();
} else {
    is.open("c:/tmp/input2.txt");
    std::cout << "false: " << is.rdbuf();
}
```

Edited january 2019 ...
you now can emulate what I explained could not be done ...

This works for moveable classes like ifstream in C++11
and even for non copiable classes since C++17 with copy elision.

Edited May 2019: use auto to alleviate verbosity

```
{
    if (auto is = std::ifstream ("missing.txt")) { // ok now !
        std::cout << "true: " << is.rdbuf();
    } else {
        is.open("main.cpp");
        std::cout << "false: " << is.rdbuf();
    }
}
struct NoCpy {
    int i;
    int j;
    NoCpy(int ii = 0, int jj = 0) : i (ii), j (jj) {}
    NoCpy(NoCpy&) = delete;
    NoCpy(NoCpy&&) = delete;
    operator bool() const {return i == j;}
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const NoCpy & x) {
        return os << "(" << x.i << ", " << x.j << ")";
    }
};
{
    auto x = NoCpy(); // ok compiles
    // auto y = x; // does not compile
    if (auto nocpy = NoCpy (7, 8)) {
        std::cout << "true: " << nocpy << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "false: " << nocpy << std::endl;
    }
}
```