# Defining a variable in the condition part of an if-statement does not allow comparison of its value. Why?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, standards

**Summary**

This question is related to: [Defining a variable in the condition part of an if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655284/defining-a-variable-in-the-condition-part-of-an-if-statement).

So, why I can't check the value of the newly defined variable in the same place?

---

**Simple example**

In other words, this is allowed (from the linked question):

```
if( int* x = new int( 20 ) ) 
{   
    std::cout << *x << "!\n";
    delete x;
}
```

but this isn't:

```
if( NULL != ( int* x = new int( 20 ) ) )
{   
    std::cout << *x << "!\n";
    delete x;
}
```

The second one gives me:

```
test.cpp:xx: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
test.cpp:xx: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
```

---

**Question**

And (maybe) the more important question here - how is the condition of the first `if` evaluated? According to my tests, it seems like both options do the same - there's implicit check against `false` (`0`, `NULL`, whatever). But is it guaranteed by the standard?

---

**Real-world example**

OK, I can't check the new variable against some custom value, but I can compare it against `false`. So, here's a real-world example: I have a class, containing a `template` method: `check_class`. This method does a `dynamic_cast` of an internal pointer. Now I want to use it like:

```
if( some_class* some_class_ptr = cmd->check_class< some_class >() )
{
     // some_class_ptr is NOT NULL here
}
else if( other_class* other_class_ptr = cmd->check_class< other_class > )
{
    // other_class_ptr is NOT NULL here
}
// ...
```

The reason to want this is that the `if` will be pretty long and I don't want to declare all variables before it.

Comment: This code looks very confusing to me.

Comment: @DanielDaranas - which part exactly?

Comment: You can. in [GO](http://golang.org/).

Comment: @KirilKirov _Any_ boolean expression which as secondary effects, such as "int* x = new int( 20 )" inside if(...).

Comment: The problem is exactly the same as trying to write this statement: 'NULL != ( int* x = new int( 20 );'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, why I can't check the value of the newly defined variable in the same place?

Because the syntax doesn't allow it. The condition can be either a *declaration* or an *expression*. An expression can't declare a named variable, and a declaration can't be used as an expression.

> how is the condition of the first if evaluated?

The variable is initialised, and its value converted to `bool`. The condition succeeds if that yields `true`.

> But is it guaranteed by the standard?

Yes:

> C++11 6.4/3 The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a `switch` statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted to `bool`.

Comment: "The condition can be either a declaration or an expression" - this explains a lot. And a quote from _the Standard_ is _always_ a big plus. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason lies in the grammar of the language. In a nutshell, the code in the `if` condition (and similar constructs) can either be a declaration or an expression. When it's a declaration, there is of course no syntax to compare the declared entity to something.

When it's an expression, it's like any other expression anywhere else in code. Just as you cannot write this:

```
int foo() {
  bar(4 + (int b = 7));
}
```

you cannot put the same into an `if`.

Why it works with comparing against `true` is that when the code in the `if` is a declaration, the condition is evaluated as "the declared object contextually converted to bool."

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Nice answer, I accepted the other because of the quote from the standard. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

> how is the condition of the first `if` evaluated?

As you seem to think. The following

```
if( int* x = new int( 20 ) ) 
{   
    std::cout << *x << "!\n";
    delete x;
}
```

is "roughly" equivalent to

```
{
   int* x = new int( 20 );
   if( x ) 
   {   
       std::cout << *x << "!\n";
       delete x;
   }   
}
```

and in the test `if( x )` the expression `x` is implicitly converted to `bool`, which means `if( x != 0 )` (or `if( x != NULL )`).