# Incorrectly phrased IF Statement from C++ SDK

Tags: c++, api, if-statement, sdk

I have been using an SDK for Alpaca Markets that was created by another person and released on GitHub. This code contains an IF Statement which does not seem like it is formatted correctly to me, but I am somewhat new to C++. It is pasted below

The if statement does not appear to actually be checking any Boolean values. The code will also fail to compile when this statement is included. The solution I found was to comment it out and set the variables within the config.cpp file.

Is this simply just a mistake?

```
if (auto e = std::getenv(api_key_id_env_var_.c_str())){
  api_key_id_ = std::str(e);
} else {
  return Status(1, api_key_id_env_var_ + " is not set.");
}
```

Comment: At first grance it looked duplicate of [c++ - Defining a variable in the condition part of an if-statement? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655284/defining-a-variable-in-the-condition-part-of-an-if-statement)

Comment: But it actually looks weird because There isn't `)` after `c_str())` and there isn't `);` after `" is not set." `.

Comment: Have you enabled c++17?

Answer (score 0):

> The if statement does not appear to actually be checking any Boolean values.

It is declaring and initializating the `e` variable with the result of calling `std::getenv()`, and is then testing if `e` is non-zero. Since `getenv()` returns a `char*`, the `auto` type of `e` is deduced as `char*`, and thus checking if `e` is non-zero means checking if it is not `nullptr`.

The code is just shorthand for doing this:

```cpp
{
   char* e = std::getenv(api_key_id_env_var_.c_str());
   if (e != nullptr){
      api_key_id_ = std::str(e);
   } else {
      return Status(1, api_key_id_env_var_ + " is not set.");
   } 
}
```